# BASH - How to combine data from 2 files

Tags: bash, script, sed, text-editing, text-formatting

I have 2 files with the following data

`file1`:

```
datapoint1name##datapoint1name
datapoint1name.PercentUtilization=
datapoint2name##datapoint2name
datapoint2name.PercentUtilization=
datapoint3name##datapoint3name
datapoint3name.PercentUtilization=
```

`file2`:

```
74.5
64.9
48.5
```

How can I achieve this in a single file?

```
datapoint1name##datapoint1name
datapoint1name.PercentUtilization=74.5
datapoint2name##datapoint2name
datapoint2name.PercentUtilization=64.9
datapoint3name##datapoint3name
datapoint3name.PercentUtilization=48.5
```

I'll have an indefinate amount of datapoints in this file but the structure here will remain constant.

Comment: 1) yes, its a regular file 2) There should be no leading spaces, my fault there. 3) I only showed 3 lines in the 2nd file for the example. In the desired output the data from file2 only needs to be appended to the end of "PercentUtilization=" line. Hours of googling and various while and for loops to no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed 's/^/\n/' file2 | paste -d '' file1 -
```

<sup>(Note: there is nothing specific to Bash in the above command.)</sup>

At first `sed` injects empty lines into data from `file2`. Then `paste` appends the result to the lines from `file1`.

The empty lines come from `sed` as the 1st, 3rd, 5th line, etc., they are appended to odd lines from `file1` so these lines don't change. The actual lines from `file2` come from `sed` as the 2nd, 4th, 6th line, etc., they are appended to even lines from `file1`.